# Can not get developer key on Google Console

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use `Youtube Data API` to create request, the code here:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("YoutubeUpload", "developer_key", "myemail@gmail.com", "mypass");

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

var feed = request.GetStandardFeed(YouTubeQuery.MostPopular);
```

But I could not found `"developer key"` on google console. Google's document specify link to get developer key: https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/

But it can not log in.
Can you help me create a simple request to Youtube Data API

Thank you so much!

Comment: what is settings?  Its not part of the YouTube api that I can see and I cant seam to access that link you posted.   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything Google refer to as a 'Developer Key' - but you can get/create Credentials at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials